# Probability permutation in turned to cycle

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, permutations, cycles

Let $M$ be a $0/1$ square matrix having one $1$ per row and column (permutation matrix).

If you permute the columns and rows independently what is the probability resulting permutation matrix is a complete cycle?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#A_variation_on_the_100_prisoners_problem_(keys_and_boxes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $M$ is $n\times n$, the probability is $1/n$.

Indeed, by symmetry, the probability in question is the probability that a random permutation of $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a complete cycle:
If the $(i,j)$-entry of $M$ is $M_{i,j}=1(j=\pi(i))$ for some permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ and all $i,j$ in $[n]$, then after applying random permutations $\rho$ and $\sigma$ to the rows and columns of $M$, respectively, the $(i,j)$-entry of the resulting random permutation matrix will be
$$1(\sigma(j)=\pi(\rho(i)))=1(j=(\sigma^{-1}\circ\pi\circ\rho)(i))),$$
and, by symmetry, all values of the random permutation $\sigma^{-1}\circ\pi\circ\rho$ are equally probable.

There are $n!$ permutations of $[n]$. Of these $n!$ permutations, $(n-1)!$ are complete cycles (indeed, to construct any cycle, we can set $1$ in the first position, and then put $2,\dots,n$ in any order). So, the probability in question is $(n-1)!/n!=1/n$.

Comment: I see and so we require $\#\mbox{random column permutations}\times\#\mbox{random row permutations}=n^\alpha\times n^\beta$ where $\alpha+\beta\geq1$ to get probability at least $\frac{1}{O(1)}$?